# How to find a substring from a string with certain condition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring

I have record like this

```
A                          Result
Hello AP#12/22 Welcome     AP#12
Thanks AP#123-21           AP#123
No problem AP#111          AP#111
```

So as you can see i need the AP code from the string. It must not contain the - or / part.

> Note:
>
> AP code can be of any number of digit
>
> It can appear at the end or start
>
> AP code can be followed by / or - or any other special symbol such as
>   : or any other.

So i need a generalized formula rather than checking for each special character(/, -, :) to get AP code.

I want to achieve this without using VB.

Comment: You should use Regex. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @Luuklag thx. But i want to do it without using vba if possible.

Comment: That should also be possible, using multiple combinations of the Instring, left and right functions. Would be a lot of work though, seeing there are plenty possibile seperators in your case.

Comment: Does it always start with `AP#`? And what is the max amount of numbers that can follow afterwards?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Yes it always starts with AP# but can have as many as 3 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution... but here's a way without VBA: (line break added for readability)

```
= "AP#"&MID(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1)+3,999),1,
  MAX((ISNUMBER(MID(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1)+3,999),{1,2,3},1)+0)+0)*{1,2,3}))
```

---

**EDIT**

Slightly better solution:

```
= MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1),
  MAX(ISNUMBER(MID(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1)+3,999),{1,2,3},1)+0)*{1,2,3})+3)
```

---

**EDIT** (again)

As pointed out in comment, this does not take into account something like `AP#1-1`. Here is the updated formula that will take this into account:

```
= MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1),IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE,
  ISNUMBER(MID(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1)+3,3),{1,2,3},1)+0),0),4)+2)
```

---

As requested, here is how this formula works. I'll break it down step by step. This is a pretty long explanation but if you just take it one step at a time, I think you should be able to understand the entire formula. I'm going to explain what is going on from the inside out.

`FIND("AP#",A1)` returns the character index number in `A1` where the first instance of `AP#` appears in `A1`.

For simplicity, I will refer to `FIND("AP#",A1)` as `<x1>` in the next step.

`MID(A1,<x1>+3,3)` returns the 3 characters in `A1` that appear immediately after `AP#`. It only returns 3 characters because from the original problem, you said that up to 3 numbers can appear after `AP#`.

(Quick note: Originally I had this part of the formula as `MID(A1,<x1>+3,999)` but after making this explanation, I realized that `999` could be reduced to `3`. `999` would still work, just that `3` is simpler and makes the formula more efficient.)

I will refer to this value `MID(A1,<x1>+3,3)` as `<x2>` in the next step.

`MID(<x2>,{1,2,3},1)` essentially converts `<x2>` which is a string of 3 characters, to a *array* of 3 strings, each string 1 character long. In other words, if `<x2>` is (for example), `"1-2"`, then that means `MID(<x2>,{1,2,3},1)` is `{"1","-","2"}`. It is necessary to convert a string of 3 characters to a 1x3 array of single characters in order to individually analyze each character.

I will refer to `MID(<x2>,{1,2,3},1)` as `<x3>` in the next step.

`<x3>+0` may seem like a simple step but there is a lot going on here. Keep in mind `<x3>` is still an array of *strings*, not *numbers* (even if they *look like* numbers). The `+0` will convert all strings that look like numbers to numbers, and will convert all strings that *don't* look like numbers to an error value. (In this case, `#VALUE!`.)

Sticking with our same example, `{"1","-","2"}+0` will equal `{1,#VALUE!,2}`.

I will refer to `<x3>+0` as `<x4>` in the next step.

`MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(<x4>),0)` returns the first index of `<x4>` where it is *not* a number. The idea here is to find the index of the first non-number, and then include everything up to that index (minus one).

Sticking with our same example, `MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER({1,#VALUE!,2}),0)` would return `2`, because the 2nd index in `{1,#VALUE!,2}` is the first index that is not a number.

I will refer to `MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(<x4>),0)` as `<x5>` in the next step.

It is possible that all values in `<x4>` are numbers, in which case `<x5>` would return an error because it can't find a match for a non-number. `IFERROR(<x5>,4)` fixes this issue. It returns the value `4` if all values in `<x5>` are numbers. The reason to return `4` is because we are basically saying that all 3 of the characters following `AP#` are numbers, so the first index that we *aren't* considering after `AP#` is the 4th index.

I will refer to `IFERROR(<x5>,4)` as `<x6>` in the next step.

`<x6>+2` may seem like a strange calculation, and it is, so I will write it a different way that will make more sense: `(<x6>-1)+3`

Remember what `<x6>` represents here: It is the index of the *first non-number* that appears in the string of 3 characters *after* `AP#` . Therefore, `<x6>-1` is the number of characters to include after `AP#`.

Now, why add 3? `(<x6>-1)+3` is necessary to include the 3 characters in `AP#` itself. This will make sense in the next step.

I will refer to `<x6>+2` as `<x7>` in the next step.

`MID(A1,FIND(AP#,A1),<x7>)` returns a portion of string `A1`, starting at the `A` in `AP#` and spanning `<x7>` characters. And how large is `<x7>`? It is however many numbers are in the `AP#` code, plus 3. (Again, we must add 3 to include the 3 `AP#` characters themselves in the calculation.)

This is the entire calculation.

Come to think of it, you may want to wrap an `IFERROR` around the entire calculation to take care of cases where `AP#` isn't found in the string, e.g. something like:

```
= IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1),IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE,
  ISNUMBER(MID(MID(A1,FIND("AP#",A1)+3,3),{1,2,3},1)+0),0),4)+2),"no match")
```

But really that is your call. I'm not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: it is not working for this example - abc paid by AP#7-679 for jan17. it is returning AP#7-6 instead of AP#7.

Comment: @Raj Ah, good point. I hadn't thought of this scenario originally. See my answer again, I updated based on this. It should work now.

Comment: Thnx. its working now i will accept your answer. It would be great if you could explain the logic behind the formula so that i could use it in other work as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Raj See my answer again. I edited to explain formula.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function FindAPcode(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, CH As String, i As Long, j As Long

    FindAPcode = ""
    L = Len(s)
    If L = 0 Then Exit Function
    j = InStr(1, s, "AP#") + 3
    If j = 3 Then Exit Function
    FindAPcode = "AP#"

    For i = j To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            FindAPcode = FindAPcode & CH
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
     Next i
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**